# cannot add driver for fcurve noise values

Tags: modifiers, drivers, fcurves

I am not able to add any driver to this noise-modifier values.

Ok, i can accept that it is that way. But until now nearly every value i could "drive" with drivers. Is there a special reason for this?

And is there some workaround possible?

Reason is: I want to copy an object with animation + noise modifier but each noise modifier should have different offset/strength values which i would like to randomize.

[image]

Comment: Marty Fouts (a wee bit grumpy, LOL) writes [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/261872/111042).  I want this candy also!