# How do I drive F-curve Modifier properties?

Tags: modifiers, drivers, graph-editor, fcurves, custom-attributes

I want to control the F-curve Modifier properties such as amplitude, phase multiplier, etc, by means of a driver/custom property. Modifier properties don't appear to be driver enabled or animatable. Is there any way to achieve this without scripting? If not, why isn't that feature available? Also, If scripting is the only option, could I be given a bit of direction in where would be the best place to start learning python that is blender relevant. Thank you

This is a specific question so I won't bother uploading the project file.

Comment: You can't.  Because there's a long list of features that people want and only 12 developers.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm not a coder, so I didn't know whether it was that or if it was not possible for technical reasons. It would be a very valuable feature. EX: using a sine wav modifier to animate a fish swimming, and having a driver/property setup to affect the amplitude and therefore increase/decrease the fish's swimming wriggle relative to speed.

The fact it doesn't exist is good motivation for me to starting diving into scripting.